# iOS what is the most energy efficient way to get near by iBeacons when in the app is in background

Tags: ios, core-location, core-bluetooth

I am building an app that require me to continuously save iBeacons that match my uuid that are near by. I have used region monitoring, and region ranging when within region. When I do this in the background, it seem to take up about 7% of the battery every hour.

Any thoughts on making this efficient? is there a different way to do this instead of using CoreLocation?

Comment: Try Significant-Change Location Service? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

Comment: Do you really need to continually range the beacons?  If so then you are going to incur significant energy use.  If you can live with just region entry/exit then energy use will be less.

Comment: @YunCHEN the rules for when Significant change call back happens is not very clear, and it seems it can take minutes before you get this call.

Comment: @Paulw11 how the boundary is defined for when I'm "in range" is not very clear. Also, in my testing it looks like when you are in range, it takes at least 30 seconds before the didEnterRegion call. My application is for indoor navigation, and I either need to continue to beacon from the app (which is not supported in background mode), or to range for beacons and calculate locations based on rssi values. if you have any creative ideas let me know - thx

Comment: There is a deliberate hysterisis in the region entry/exit notification to prevent flapping when a device is on the edge of the beacon's range. Continuous navigation is typically an energy expensive operation. If you need to range beacons continually then you are going to use energy to do so. It is unavoidable.

Comment: @Paulw11 the only functionality I need from CoreLocation is to get a list of beacons and it's RSSI values. do you know if there is any way I can get this information just by using CoreBluetooth? it seems LocationManager is a huge overhead for the one piece of functionality I need.

Comment: No, core Bluetooth cannot see beacons. Even if it could, regardless of whether you used core Bluetooth or core location the energy impact will be the same since it is coming from the Bluetooth radio and CPU consumption (primarily the latter I would guess as the bluetooth receiver should not use much power)